# POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ajax, backend

I have been configuring my database that is linked with nodejs in the same folder, to be able to advance a little more as a programmer, and I try to make an ajax request to the database, but it gives me an error as if the database was off or the url was wrong

```
  POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the petition code

```
userLogin = (username, password) =>{
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.7:3000/api/login'
    console.log('hola')
    fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data =>{
      if(data.status === 200){
        console.log('hola')
        this.setState({
          status: data.status,
          message: data.message,
          username: username
        })
        this.userSearch()
      }
    })
  }
```

Routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();
const controllers = require('../controllers/controllers')
const cors = require('cors')



api.post('/register', controllers.registerUser)
api.post('/login', controllers.loginUsers)
api.get('/test',  controllers.test)

module.exports = api;
```

I have already made ajax requests before but the time I do it within the same node.js, if someone knows how to solve it please help me

Comment: I'm seeing 2 URLs in your code. Is your database API supposed to be exposed on `http://192.168.1.7:3000` or `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: If I use 2 but none makes the POST request, but trying a little more, and I see that another route than me to do tests I have that is type get if it worksIf I use 2 but none makes the POST request, but trying a little more, and I see that another route than me to do tests I have that is type get if it works

Comment: Where are you creating the server?

Comment: Mern Stack, using react with nodejs inside my pc

Comment: I don't see where you defined the `api/` prefix. Aren't the routes supposed to be e.g. `/login` instead of `/api/login`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = express();
const controllers = require('../controllers/controllers')
const cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3013;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOption));

var server = require('http').Server(app);

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Updated : Server listening at ports', port);
});

app.post('/api/register', controllers.registerUser)
app.post('/api/login', controllers.loginUsers)
aapppi.get('/api/test',  controllers.test)
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your code is different from the author's code.